# Change protocol of Elastic Beanstalk health checker to HTTPS instead of plain HTTP (Application load balancer)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I just recently added [this](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/resource-configuration/alb-http-to-https-redirection.config) HTTPS redirect config file to my EB project, and now all health checks are failing because all the responses are 3XX and not 2XX.

The 3xx is caused by a redirect from http -> https that the config file I added enforces.

I couldn't find any solutions to that in the docs.
I'm open to alternatives, maybe making the health-check pass if it the endpoint returns 3xx?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I have configured Django to also do HTTPS redirects. Now that I turned this off and solely rely on the load balancer for this, the error is gone.